# Bootstrap 3 navbar-right not collapsing at tablet width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic Bootstrap 3 navbar with a navbar-right dropdown but when I reduce it from large desktop to tablet size, rather than collapse it jumps below the main menu?
http://www.doorsets.org.uk/apollodoors/index.html

I would guess this is to do with making a change in the media query section but I'm not sure what I need to change.  Can anyone help?

Much appreciated
NJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bootstrap's documentation on this subject:

> Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than
> @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least @grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

So if you want the nav-bar to collapse on bigger screens, you need to change the value of @grid-float-breakpoint to something that suits you, maybe 900px, or, in less @screen-md-min.

Comment: I've done a find/replace across my entire site and can't find "grid-float-breakpoint".  How do I edit this setting and which core file should it be within?

Comment: It depends how you are integrating Bootstrap with your site. Are you linking to the Bootstrap CDN or did you download files from the Bootstrap website? If you went with the second option, you can redownload a customized Bootstrap from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) after modifying @grid-float-breakpoint.

Comment: I have downloaded Bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ which gives me CSS, FONTS and JS folders and associated files.  There is no @grid-float-breakpoint in any of it, which is most confusing considering the above advice.

Comment: OK, instead of downloading it from there, go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and modify the @grid-float-breakpoint variable. Then click "Compile and Download" at the bottom of the page and use this version instead of the previous one.

Comment: Just to clarify, @grid-float-breakpoint is a LESS variable which are not available in the CSS but used to produce the CSS files. That is why you won't find it in CSS, Fonts and JS folders.

Comment: I changed the @grid-float-breakpoint from screen-sm-min to screen-md-min and that seems to have done the trick. Thank you.  Why is it set up incorrectly in the first place though?

Comment: @NathonJones There is no single canonical answer for when a navbar should (un)collapse. It depends on the actual contents of your particular navbar. Are tablets more mobile-ish or desktop-ish? That's a matter of open debate. Bootstrap happened to choose SM-sized screens as the default, which is a perfectly reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

@NicoFerma is correct and the "grid-float-breakpoint" is the variable to change if configuring a new boostrap install. However, if you don't want to install a new version of bootstap, this simple find/replace in the boostrap.min.css/boostrap.css file has just worked for me:

Find

```
@media(min-width:768px
```

Replace with

```
@media(min-width:922px
```

*Modify the min-width px to your preferred nav-bar swithchpoint

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
            position: static;
            float: none;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            clear: both;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #333;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .navbar-header {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-toggle {
            display: block;
        }
        .navbar-collapse {
            border-top: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
        .navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: none!important;
        }
        .navbar-nav {
            float: none!important;
            /*margin: 7.5px -15px;*/
            margin: 7.5px 50px 7.5px -15px
        }
        .navbar-nav>li {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav>li>a {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .navbar-text {
            float: none;
            margin: 15px 0;
        }
        /* since 3.1.0 */
        .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
            display: block!important;
        }
        .collapsing {
            overflow: hidden!important;
        }
    }
```